# Bash script to check which port is listening and run a command if it is

Tags: bash, port

I am new on bash scripting and I am trying to write a bash script in which starting from certain port, check if it is listening, if it is, run a command and if it is not increment the port number until it finds one which is listening, any help would be much appreciated.

```
PORT=8080
a=$(netstat -plnt | grep $PORT | awk '{print $6}')
#echo $a;exit
while [ "$a" != "LISTEN" ]
do
 (( PORT=PORT+1 ))
 printf "Port number is $PORT\n"
done
#run command
```

Comment: run a docker container when it finds an available port

Answer (score 1):

1. netstat (net-tools) is deprecated, perhaps you want to use other tools (ss, lsof, fuser etc.)
2. even though the netstat is deprecated, you may want to have `u` for udp as well
3. you need to run your script with root permission so that you can detect the processes, which are listening on those ports, no matter who is the owner
4. with `lsof`, you can probably save the `grep` and `awk` processes, like: `(root) lsof -i :8080`

**Another thing you may want to consider:**

Instead of `loop(port++ -> check)`, you may want to first get all "occupied" ports, then pick a free slot. otherwise you may run netstat (or other tools) dozen ~ hundreds times.

Comment: Why was netstat deprecated? Is it only in Debian? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278474/why-is-netstat-deprecated

Comment: @stephanmg yes it is. pls read the netstat man page. also https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2009/03/msg00780.html

Answer (score 1):

#### There are some issues:

- searching for $PORT on whole line of `netstat -tnlp` will match if any PID match `.*8080.*` (process 8080, 18080 .. 58080)
- `grep | awk` could by simplified.
- strange loop who print each port number until free port!?

#### But as this run on Linux based server

You could use `/proc/net/tcp` instead of `netstat`, then

- In `/proc/net/tcp*`, 4th column display `0A` if *LISTEN*
- IP Addesss and ports are hexadecimals.
- `/proc/net/tcp*` will refer to both `/proc/net/tcp` and `/proc/net/tcp6`

So:

```
PORT=8080
while printf -v regex ':%04X .* 0A ' $PORT;grep -q "$regex" /proc/net/tcp*;do
    ((PORT++))
  done
echo First free port number: $PORT
```

must do the job.

#### Alternative: *Take occupied ports out of a list*

Creating a list of *unused ports* (from 8080 to 10000):

```
freeport() { 
    local _allPorts
    printf -v _allPorts "[%s]='' " {8080..10000}
    local -a _allPorts="($_allPorts)"
    local _procFile _port _state
    for _procFile in tcp{,6}; do
      { 
        read _
        while IFS=$' :\r\t\n' read _ _ _port _ _ _state _; do
            [ "$_state" = "0A" ] && unset "_allPorts[16#$_port]"
        done
      } < /proc/net/$_procFile
    done
    local _freePorts=(${!_allPorts[@]})
    echo "First free port: $_freePorts"
    echo "All free ports: ${_freePorts[*]::6} ...(+$((
             ${#_freePorts[@]}-9))more)  ${_freePorts[*]: -3}"
}
```

Then

```
$ freeport
First free port: 8082
All free ports: 8082 8083 8089 8090 8091 8092 ...(+1904more)  9998 9999 10000
```

As this is *pure bash* (there are no fork), this function is very quick.

In order to reuse result, think using a *nameref* to populate a variable from function instead of use `result=$(freeport)`, wich implie a fork.

#### Full and useful function:

```
freeport() {
    local _allPorts _procFile _port _state
    if [[ $1 == -v ]] ;then
        local -n _freePorts=$2;shift 2
    else
        local _freePorts
    fi
    for ((_port=${1:-8080};_port<=${2:-10000};_port++)) ;do
            _allPorts[_port]=
    done
    for _procFile in tcp{,6}; do
      { 
        read _
        while IFS=$' :\r\t\n' read _ _ _port _ _ _state _; do
            [ "$_state" = "0A" ] && unset "_allPorts[16#$_port]"
        done
      } < /proc/net/$_procFile
    done
    _freePorts=(${!_allPorts[@]})
    if [[ ${_freePorts@A} == declare\ -a\ _freePorts=* ]];then
        if (( ${#_freePorts[@]} > 9 )) ;then
            printf 'First free port: %d\nAll free ports: %s ...(+%d more) %s\n'\
               "$_freePorts" "${_freePorts[*]::6}" $((${#_freePorts[@]}-9)) \
               "${_freePorts[*]: -3}"
        else
            printf 'First free port: %d\nAll free ports: %s\n'\
               "$_freePorts" "${_freePorts[*]}"
        fi
    fi
    [[ -v _freePorts[0] ]] # return false if no free port found.
}
```

Then

```
$ freeport 
First free port: 8082
All free ports: 8082 8083 8089 8090 8091 8092 ...(+1904 more) 9998 9999 10000

$ freeport 8080 8090
First free port: 8082
All free ports: 8082 8083 8089 8090

$ freeport -v myArray 8080 8090
$ declare -p myArray
declare -a myArray=([0]="8082" [1]="8083" [2]="8089" [3]="8090")
```

(And yes, there is a lot of tcp port in 808x open on my host.)

Comment: Can be done in pure bash without spawning an external command and also account for IPv6: `PORT=8080; while [[ "$(</proc/net/tcp)$(</proc/net/tcp6)" =~ $(printf ':%04X .* 0A ' $PORT) ]]; do ((PORT++)); done; echo "$PORT"`

Comment: @LéaGris I'm careful with bash's regex! Specially reading whole files like this, who could become very big on high loaded servers.

Comment: @LéaGris Syntax `... $(printf ...)` would implie a fork! `printf -v myvar; ... "$myvar" ...` may prevent them.

Comment: But @LéaGris thanks for drawing my attention to `tcp` **and** `tcp6`! Answer corrected!

Comment: or `/proc/net/@(tc|ud)p@(6|)`

Comment: or `/proc/net/{tc,ud}p{,6}` , but `udp` is not `tcp`. If you want to start a server, you may want to know wich protocol is used.

Comment: @LéaGris Added double-quotes around `[..]` in unset command, in order to avoid bash expansion trying to match content of bracket with current folder content.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `netstat -l --program`  instead